# Is it hopeless to try and solve this equation analytically?

Tags: numerical-methods, riemann-zeta, riemann-hypothesis, transcendental-equations

Can this equation be solved with analytical methods, or is it only numeric methods since current mathematical tools don't go that far? Its complex roots are the same as the roots of the zeta function on the critical strip.

I already know the positive odd integers $k$ are zeros, and the trivial zeros of the eta function ($1+2\pi i\,n/\log{2}$), $n$ integer, are also zeros. But I am more concerned with the complex zeros.

$$k-1=\frac{\pi}{2}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\left(\sec{v}\,\text{csch}{\frac{\pi\tan{v}}{2}}\right)^2\left(1-\frac{\cos{k\,v}}{(\cos{v})^k}\right)\,dv$$

Perhaps a better form is:
$$k-1=\frac{\pi}{2}\int_{0}^{\infty}\left(\text{csch}{\frac{\pi\,u}{2}}\right)^2\left(1-(1+u^2)^{k/2}\cos{(k\arctan{u})}\right)\,du$$

and the referred paper shows how it reduces for integer $k$.

This is not a conjecture, I derived this result, perhaps will post the link here later. The help I need is with ways to solve the equation analytically. When I try to use the Weierstrass factorization theorem using only these 3 classes of zeros, the values don't add up, so something is amiss (maybe more zeros exist).

Edit: Paper [A new approach to the Riemann hypothesis](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/346552243_A_new_approach_to_the_Riemann_hypothesis)

Plot of $f(k)=1-k+g(k)$ for real $k$, where $g(k)$ is the integral:

[image]

[image]

It goes crazy near some points (explodes), it seems to always grow for negative $k$, though it's the non-real roots that are of interest.

Comment: Have you tried splitting the integral into its two parts and looking at them separately?

Comment: No, they don't converge separately. I already threw the towel, expecting someone with more brainpower than me to show me the yellow brick road, or better yet, show me the solution. It's gotta be there somewhere.

Comment: @ThomasJunior Are you sure Odd positive integers are solutions? I see this is true for $k=1$, but for others...Numerically, in terms of real solution, after $k =1$, I see $k \approx 7.50256$.

Comment: @ThomasJunior And there do not seem to exist Complex solutions.

Comment: @PierreCarre Try NIntegrate in Mathematica? It works.

Comment: @PierreCarre See the graph I added.

Comment: @ThomasJunior Yes, you are correct, I also used Mathematica but I inserted the wrong expression (left the $k-1$ part out of the absolute value in the complex case).

Comment: @PierreCarre. Could you give one or two values of $k$ leading to complex results ? Thanks.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici When I was talking about complex solutions, I meant complex values of $k$ that solve the equation. Plotting the contours of $g(a,b)=\left| (a+bi)-1- \frac{\pi}{2}\int_0^{\pi/2} (\cdots) dv\right|$ it seems that there are no complex values of $k$ that solve the equation.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: I think it's the same graph repeated, except with a different scaling on the y-axis (i.e. $f(k)$ axis)

Comment: Taking $\rho_n$ the n-th non-trival zero of the analytically continued zeta function, the conjecture is I believe
$$\frac{\pi}{2}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\left(\sec{v}\,\text{csch}{\frac{\pi\tan{v}}{2}}\right)^2\left(1-\frac{\cos{(\rho_n\,v)}}{(\cos{v})^{\rho_n}}\right)\,dv+(1-\rho_n)=f(k)=0.$$ I have verified this using Mathematica for the first five $\rho_n$ to 200 d.p.
Interestingly there also appears to be a link between the integral $g(k)$ (in substituted form) and the primes, via pascals triangle.

Comment: See the link to my paper. I will be posting it after I add a certain update.

Comment: @JamesArathoon It's not a conjecture, I derived that equation.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici The trivial zeros of the eta function should also be zeros.

Answer (score 1):

**Long Comment:**

Using the tangent half-angle substitution I get (with little help from Mathematica)
$$f(k)=(1-k)+\frac{ \pi}{2}  \int_0^{\infty } \text{csch}^2\left(\frac{\pi  t}{2}\right) \left(1-\frac{T_k\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{t^2+1}}\right)}{\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{t^2+1}}\right)^k}\right) \, dt \tag{1}$$

where $T_k$ is the [Chebyshev polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials) of the first kind.

The function $ \left(1-\frac{T_k\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{t^2+1}}\right)}{\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{t^2+1}}\right)^k}\right)$ has some interesting divisibility properties involving prime $k>2$ and $t=1,2,3,...$

for $t=1$ for example, the resulting $1-2^{k/2} \cos \left(\frac{\pi  k}{4}\right)$ generates a sequence of integers (2) in $k$ that appear to be divisible by prime $k>2$ only.

$0,1,3,5,5,1,-7,-15,-15,1,33,65,65,1,-127,-255,-255,1,513,1025,... \tag{2}$

I can't find this sequence in OEIS. (**Update 2:** Add 1 to each number in sequence (2) and you will find it + others with sign differences etc.)

for $t=2$ the resulting terms in $k$ are also divisible other values of $k$ including powers of 2.

Alternatively integral (1) can be written

$$ \frac{\pi}{2} \int_0^{\infty }  \text{csch}^2\left(\frac{\pi  t}{2}\right) \left(1-\left(t^2+1\right)^{k/2} \cos \left(k \sec ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{t^2+1}\right)\right)\right) \, dt$$

Very quick Search of the internet reveals some hits to active academic research e.g. https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.09251

**Update:**

The above integral seems related to the slightly simpler integral below:

$$\frac{\pi}{2} \int_0^{\infty }    \text{sech}^2\left(\frac{\pi  t}{2}\right) \left(\left(t^2+1\right)^{k/2} \cos \left(k \sec ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{t^2+1}\right)\right)\right) \, dt\tag{3}$$

The first few Riemann Zeta Function non-trivial zero's I tried are also zero's for this integral function.

[image]

**Update 2:**
A simpler and perhaps more beautiful formula is equivalent to (3) in terms of  the first few non-trivial zero's

$$\frac{\pi}{4} \int_0^{\infty }  \text{sech}^2\left(\frac{\pi  t}{2}\right)  \left((1+i t)^k+(1-i t)^k\right)  \, dt$$

see https://oeis.org/A146559  (Paolo P. Lava, Nov 18 2008)

The conjecture is that for complex $k$ (assuming analytic continuation is valid for the Chebyshev polynomials of the first kind)

$$ \left(\frac{T_k\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{t^2+1}}\right)}{\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{t^2+1}}\right)^k}\right)=\left(\left(t^2+1\right)^{k/2} \cos \left(k \sec ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{t^2+1}\right)\right)\right)= \frac{1}{2}\left((1+i t)^k+(1-i t)^k\right) $$

where $i^2=-1$

**Update 3: Just for Reference**

$$\frac{2^{z-1}}{\Gamma (z+1)} \int_0^{ \infty } t^z \,\text{csch}^2(t) \, dt=\text{Li}_z(1)=\zeta(z)\;\; ;[z>1]$$

$$\frac{2^{z-1}}{\Gamma (z+1)} \int_0^{ \infty } t^z \,\text{sech}^2(t) \, dt=-\text{Li}_z(-1)=\eta(z)\;\; ;[z>0]$$

Comment: I've added a link to the paper.